# What is the best way to handle this sub query in laravel using DB:raw?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

After several attempts I am having trouble getting this raw query formatted using DB::raw in laravel. Could someone point me in the right direction? I am trying to avoid using DB::table or spliting it up into multiple queries if possible.

```
select id 
from ParticipantDetail 
where testId= (
    select testId from PacketDetail where PacketDetail.packetid=ParticipantDetail.packetid and  [order]='1'
) 
and packetid = (
    select packetid from ParticipantDetail where id = '1f4716e9-6e8b-41ce-b746-60a013fab38f'
)
and masterid = (
    select masterid from ParticipantDetail where id = '1f4716e9-6e8b-41ce-b746-60a013fab38f'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to make these sub-queries

I changed the query a little bit. and used DB::select() to run it.

```
DB::select("select partDtl.id from ParticipantDetail partDtl
    INNER JOIN PacketDetail packDtl on packDtl.packetid = partDtl.packetid
    WHERE partDtl.id = ? and packDtl.order = ?",
     ['1f4716e9-6e8b-41ce-b746-60a013fab38f', '1']);
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Looking good! I dont think the testId got into the query